# Remove trailing zeroes from ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, java-stream

For a given input ArrayList I want all leading or 0s in between non-zero elements to remain, but want to get rid of any number of trailing 0s in the ArrayList.

Input:

> 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 0, 0, 0

Expected output:

> 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11

My solution:

```
    private List<Integer> foo() {

        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 0, 0, 0);
        Collections.reverse(list);
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
        int i = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext() && 0 != iterator.next()) {
            ++i;
        }
        return list.subList(0, i);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is your program giving incorrect output?  If so, please include it in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just remove the last element if it's a `0`.  Repeat until it's not.

e.g.

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 0, 0, 0));
    while (list.get(list.size()-1) == 0) {
        list.remove(list.size()-1);
    }
    System.out.println(list); // [0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

Three things needs to change in your code

In the condition where you are iterating, make it like this, you want to keep counting zeros

```
while (iterator.hasNext() && 0 == iterator.next()) {
```

Reverse after you count the trailing zeros

```
Collections.reverse(list);
```

`sublist` it from `0` to the `list.size() - i;`

Full code

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 0, 0, 0);
Collections.reverse(list);
Iterator<Integer> iterator = list.iterator();
int i = 0;
while (iterator.hasNext() && 0 == iterator.next()) {
  ++i;
}
Collections.reverse(list);
return list.subList(0, list.size() - i);
```

Answer (score 0):

@azurefrog's solution is the simplest.

We can also take advantage of class `ListIterator` to go all the way to the end and iterate our way back while removing zeros (this is almost the only benefit I found so far of using `previous()` and `hasPrevious()`):

```
private List<Integer> foo() {

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 0, 0, 0));
    ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list.listIterator();
    // go to end
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      iterator.next();
    }        
    // remove zeros
    while (iterator.hasPrevious() && 0 == iterator.previous(list.size())) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray())); // [0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11]
    return list;
}
```

See [repl](https://repl.it/repls/ClosedBronzeMenus)

Comment: Instead of looping to the end like `while (iterator.hasNext()) { iterator.next(); }`, just use `list.listIterator(list.size())` in the first place… This can be used with a `for` loop, i.e. `for(ListIterator<Integer> i = list.listIterator(list.size()); i.hasPrevious() && 0 == i.previous(); ) i.remove();` which is almost as simple as the other answer. And there’s no need for `Arrays.toString(list.toArray())`; as you can simply print via `System.out.println(list);`, which will produce exactly the same output.

Answer (score 0):

- The question contradicts with the sample code because it mentions an ArrayList specifically (there's no ArrayList in your sample code) and says "get rid of", which implies removing items:

  - Your input list has a fixed size (via `Arrays#asList`).
  - You are using `List#subList`, which does not modify the input list.
- Because you specifically asked about ArrayList, a reasonable goal would be to avoid multiple costly resize operations. So for a problem like this, try to find the most efficient way to mutate the list at the end, after you know how/whether to mutate it.
- You are reversing the input but are not reversing the result, which means the result is mostly backwards. You would need to call `Collections#reverse` again.
- Reversing is wasteful.

  - In general, avoid making changes to an *entire* collection just to modify part of the collection (the end) or to answer questions about the collection (where do trailing zeroes begin?).
  - Because an ArrayList has fast random access, you can iterate backward from the end just as easily & quickly as from the beginning, so the reverse operation provides no benefit.

Because your question is self-contradictory, here are two approaches:

- Without mutating the original list:

  ```
  private List<Integer> foo(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
      int size = list.size();
      int lastNonZero = size - 1;

      // Iterate from the end until we hit a non-zero
      while (lastNonZero >= 0 && list.get(lastNonZero) == 0) {
          lastNonZero--;
      }

      // Truncate if there were trailing zeroes (and at least one non-zero)
      if (lastNonZero < size - 1 && lastNonZero >= 0) {
          list = list.subList(0, lastNonZero);
      }

      // Optional copy for safety:  list = new ArrayList<>(list);

      return list;
   }
  ```
- With mutation:

  ```
  private void foo(ArrayList<Integer> list) {           
      int size = list.size();
      int lastNonZero = size - 1;

      // Iterate from the end until we hit a non-zero
      while (lastNonZero >= 0 && list.get(lastNonZero) == 0) {
          lastNonZero--;
      }

      // Truncate if there were trailing zeroes (and at least one non-zero)
      if (lastNonZero < size - 1 && lastNonZero >= 0) {
          list.subList(lastNonZero + 1, size).clear();
      }
   }
  ```

Note: the fastest way to mutate the list might be to use [ArrayList#removeRange](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeRange) instead, but because it is `protected`, you would need to subclass ArrayList to call it.